# Numpy shuffle a subset of an array

Tags: python, numpy, one-hot-encoding

I am dealing with vectors of one hot encoded data, and I coding a random walk where the single step is to change randomly one of the ohencoded dimensions, picked at random as well.

Here is the code:

```py
MASK = random.choice(MASKS) #picks one of the ohencoded features (its mask)
SUB = X[MASK]
np.random.shuffle(SUB) #changes the ohencoded dimension by shuffling the 0s and single 1
X[MASK] = SUB #propagates back the new permutation
```

where `MASKS` is a list of all the masks, one per ohencoded feature, `X` is the random walker position.

Cutting to the chase, I am looking for a cleaner, more optimised way, of doing the shuffling without having to copy, permute and copy backwards. Is there a way of shuffling a subarray of a numpy array inplace?

Comment: have you tried just doing `np.random.shuffle(X[MASK])` ?

Comment: I tried and it seems to change a copy of `X`, `X` is constant.

Comment: just to be clear `X[MASK] = np.random.shuffle(X[MASK])` doesnt do it?

Comment: @DrBwts https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html `numpy.random.shuffle` is an inplace function and always returns `None`

Comment: @Learningisamess maybe share an example